# Not able to set the time for auction products, using the Ubercart Auction module

Tags: ubercart

I guess this question is for those of us using the [ubercart auction module](http://drupal.org/project/uc_auction)

This module allow you to make auction of products (of the Product Content Type generated by Ubercart). When you create a new product you have to fill the `Auction Settings` and in there you have to set the **expiration** date and time of the auction.

My problem is that I see the field to set the date **but no input is shown to fill the time (i.e.: 18:00:00).**

The README file of the module says:

> Use the "Expiration date and time" field to set the expiration time for the auction.

then I understand that this is either a bug (I already posted the issue) or I have a mis-configuration on my site.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to upgrade to the latest dev version, this is what the same fieldset looks like for me with that version:

[image: screenshot]

This is on a blank Drupal 7.14 installation with only the required modules for uc_auction enabled:

- Ubercart Auction - 7.x-1.x-dev (2011-Dec-11)
- Ubercart - 7.x-3.1
- Date - 7.x-2.5

It would be a good idea to make sure you have the latest stable versions of those contrib modules installed as well; if I remember rightly the date_popup module used to have an issue with setting the `#default_value` of a `date_popup` type field, so the problem might just be that.

Comment: I have all these modules updated to the last version. Then it must be related to the issue you mention about date_popup module, how can I go through this? I think of removing the popup calendar in the `uc_auction.module` file. After this, the date should be entered manually. What do you think?

Comment: I just tried the dev version of Date but...nope.

Comment: I guess there's another module interfering with it then (it works perfectly on a blank install as you can see from the image), I would start methodically disabling any contrib modules you have installed until you find the culprit

Comment: Rare... I just disabled all modules (130 modules) but the problem still persist. I also installed auction in a clean installation and it works fine. I give up... I will change the value `date_pop` to `textarea` to enter the date and time manually.

Comment: That's quite weird...I guess it's a configuration option or something then but I can't think what it would be. Sorry I can't help further

Comment: Thanks, I understand, you can't reproduce the problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

date still affects the product that is not auctioned. an error occured when I try to checkout with an unauctioned product. "Edit Issue Your order could not continue because one of the items you are trying to purchase using the “Buy Now” feature cannot be purchased because it has expired. Please remove the item from your cart to continue."